# Deletion of answers that venture "outside the box"

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

In response to [C ternary operator, can I omit one part?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73628945/17592432), [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73629065) has been deleted by a moderator as being "code golf" and unhelpful.

The OP asked if C allowed circumventing (omitting part of) the syntax of an expression. My answer showed a working alternative (using a "functional" technique.)

EDIT: "branchless", no "functional".

Is there a guideline as to how far is too far when answering SO questions?

Must all answers provided remain rigidly "inside the box?"

Comment: Rigidly?  No, not at all.  But your answer really doesn't address the question.  It *only* works on mathematical operations where you can produce an identity in some cases, it's barely readable, and is overall a totally impractical "solution" to the general case of *replicating one half of the ternary operator without an inline if statement*.  It's a trick that only works because of the particular toy examples the question chose.

Comment: @RyanM "produce an identity"... The OP's "absent" clause IS an implied "identity" operation. "barely readable" ... Upskilling might help there. "the general case..." Re-writing/re-framing the OP to fit inside your worldview? "without an inline if statement"... Where is the "if()" in my proposed answer?

Comment: *"Re-writing the OP to fit inside your worldview?"* I quote: "I wanted to know if there's a way to omit second or third part of the ternary operator" - I see nothing saying that they care only about mathematical operations. `if(x == y) do_something;` is also not specific to mathematical operations.

Comment: @RyanM The other "answer" (currently with 2UV's) completely departs from the "trenary operation"... Why, as my question here asks, has that other answer not been deleted based on its "unrelated-ness" to the question about omitting "second or third part of the ternary operator"? No "ternary operator" in that "answer"... Even handed (I ask again)? Again, referring to the OP, `do_something` has been given ONLY as mathematical operations... Who decides that `do_something` means a broader range of possibilities??

Comment: @RyanM -- I agree that the answer had problems, but I can see how summary deletion by a mod could seem somewhat arbitrary in this case. I suspect that if someone had flagged the answer as NAA, that flag would have been declined; some comparison of criteria for deletion vs criteria for NAA may be helpful. I may be wrong about this, though, since NAA flags seem slippery.

Comment: @adabsurdum I concur that a plain NAA flag would have been likely to be declined, though moderators have a bit of leeway in deleting answers on their own initiative for reasons outside of the standard NAA reasons (similar to 20k users and the delete-vote privilege).  I don't know if I *personally* would have deleted this (it certainly would merit a downvote, for the reasons I discuss above), though I understand why the other moderator did so.

Comment: "The OP asked if C allowed circumventing (omitting part of) the syntax of an expression. My answer showed a working alternative (using a "functional" technique.)" The question is whether it's possible to use part, and only part of a specific construct. An answer that doesn't use the construct at all is not addressing that question. Similarly, showing code using `?:` would not answer a question about whether an `else` block is necessary after `if`. (It doesn't actually matter, in this analysis, whether the answer to the original question is "yes" or "no".)

Comment: @RyanM Again I ask why the 2UV answer has not been deleted as its "solution" departs from using the "?:" expression... On what grounds is that 'answer' considered to be "AA" to the OP?? I could write a `for( )` expression that would not be "if( )` yet would `do_something` only once under a given condition... Who minds the minders? And, why is "thinking outside the box" penalised on SO?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel " An answer that doesn't use the construct at all is not addressing that question." So WHY is the other answer UV'd while my original answer is deleted by a "moderator"? Moderation shouldn't be immoderate, imho...

Comment: Why is it upvoted: because at least it *handles the general case* rather than hiding it behind tricky math that, to [quote the moderator who deleted your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628945/c-ternary-operator-can-i-omit-one-part#comment130020805_73628945), *only* works for one of their cases.  It's also not functional programming, by the way, but that's not actually relevant to this.

Comment: Are both answers necessary now that the original has been undeleted?

Comment: @HenryEcker They are two different answers. One trivially provides the "no-op" value that satisfies using the trenary operator (one of the OP questions). The other starts off explaining "trenary means 3", but answers the other OP question: "What else could I do"... People can read (or not) whichever one they choose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I took the answer in dispute to be indirect at best with respect to the *first part* of the question (does the ternary operator require all three operands), but it was indeed to responsive to the second part (what else can I use besides an `if` statement).  That it was limited in scope with respect to that part was in no way reason for deletion.

@user229044 seems to have taken the answer to be unhelpful, and that's fine, but the right response to that under the circumstances would have been to *downvote*.  Deleting the answer at their own initiative was an abuse of moderator abilities.

Comment: We all have "good days and bad days"... "All's well that ends well" -- William S. `:-)`

Answer (score 10):

This has nothing to do with "out of the box" answers. I deleted your answer because I didn't think it was a good-faith attempt to provide a serious, helpful answer to the question. I read it as a slightly sarcastic joke response.

Here's why:

- You have a single English sentence that serves no purpose but to support a pun; it offers *no* explanation for the solution you're proposing
- You include a bunch of non-obvious code that is of very little help to a novice C programmer
- Your code only works on one specific case given by OP, not in the general case
- Your code contains a single comment that I interpret as sarcastic: `No "?:" in sight!!` - this was never a stated goal of OP, and simply avoiding `?:` is trivially done any number of ways; in fact, `?:` was never necessary or appropriate here in the first place, so removing it is hardly novel
- If your answer is on-topic, then an arbitrary number of silly answers are also on-topic, for example `while (x == y) x *= 2;` is on-topic.

In all, I read your answer as a joke, riffing on the OP's (IMO) misguided requirement to avoid the simple `if` statement that is the obvious answer to their problem. If you wanted to offer a semi-serious suggestion that only partially addressed the question, a comment would have sufficed.

You have also repeatedly argued that [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73629124/229044) was unjustly left alone; the fundamental difference is I believed that answer was a good faith attempt to help OP, and by the time I had seen that answer it had also been edited to explicitly and directly answer the question (offering a GCC flag to do exactly what OP had asked about).

Comment: "...the OP's (IMO) misguided..." That is the very foundation of any "question" that seeks an answer. "an arbitrary number of ... answers are also on-topic" If they provide fodder for thought (by novices or experts) that is called "thinking outside the box", the title of this post... And, in conclusion, I apologise for trying to be light-hearted in these days of unabating doom and gloom.

Comment: @Fe2O3 If you truly believe your answer has merit and wasn't just a joke (I presume you do, given this meta question), I will undelete it, but I would hope you will at least edit in an explanation of how it works and what its advantages and disadvantages are vs the obvious solution.

Comment: In lieu of the "constructive criticism" (not) offered a few hours ago, I would appreciate the opportunity to "improve" that answer. :-)

Comment: Posted edit. Thank you for the (somewhat circuitous) opportunity to improve my answer.

Comment: @Fe2O3 generally, [we hate fun on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284390/241919) ;)

Comment: You *always* have the opportunity to edit an answer, even if it's been deleted. In fact, that's kinda the whole point of deletion: hiding it until you get a chance to edit it and bring it up to standards. @Fe2O3

Comment: Why do you now have [two answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73629442)? Posting two answers to the same question is almost always inappropriate. You should combine them and delete one.

Comment: @CodyGray Re: "edit deleted answer": Coulda sworn edit of my post deleted by moderator was unavailable to me, but I was somewhat upset at that time. If it happens again, I will remember your 'tip'. Thank you... Re: "two answers": When the first was deleted as "silly", I restated my comment under the OP as a full-blown "answer". (OP person had thanked me(!) in a comment. Wow!) Other (edited) answer responds to other OP question (roughly) "What else can I do..?" Merging them would, I think, be mixing apples & oranges. (Double the opportunity for DVs. Coming to expect those from SO old-timers.)